# Casting objects from Hibernate native multiple join query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a hibernate native sql query joining three tables, and I'm trying to retrive 3 columns from the result

---

```
public void doTestQuery() {

try (Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    String sql = "SELECT\r\n"
            + " users.username, \r\n"
            + " user_roles.role_name, \r\n"
            + " address.address\r\n"
            + "FROM\r\n"
            + " address\r\n"
            + " INNER JOIN\r\n"
            + " users\r\n"
            + " ON \r\n"
            + "     address.iduser = users.iduser\r\n"
            + " INNER JOIN\r\n"
            + " user_roles\r\n"
            + " ON \r\n"
            + " users.iduser = user_roles.iduser";
    NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);

    List<Object[]> results = query.list();
    
    for (Object[] arr : results) {

System.out.println(arr[0].toString() +" "+ arr[1].toString() +" "+ arr[2].toString());
    }
    
    transaction.commit();

}
```

---

If I replace the System.out.println with this code below, it gives me an error. Is there a way to cast objects from this kind of hibernate queries?

```
            Users user = (Users) arr[0];
            UserRoles userRole = (UserRoles) arr[1];
            Address _address = (Address) arr[2];    
            System.out.println(user.getUsername() + userRole.getRolename() + _address.getAddress());
```

---

[image: sql tables diagram]

Comment: I tried to this: NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(sql).addEntity("users", Users.class).addEntity("user_roles", UserRoles.class).addEntity("address", Address.class); but I got the same error: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.chris.servlet.dash.ManageProds] in context with path [/ChrisApps] threw exception [javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'iduser' not found.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for executing a native query ? Why can't you prepare a hql query which will return the output in entities.

Comment: because I tried and it seemed overly complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate requires special aliases to be able to fetch the data from a result set. For this purpose, Hibernate supports a special template in native SQL.

```
String sql = "SELECT "
        + " {u.*},"
        + " {r.*},"
        + " {a.*} "
        + "FROM "
        + " address a "
        + " INNER JOIN "
        + " users u "
        + " ON a.iduser = u.iduser "
        + " INNER JOIN "
        + " user_roles r "
        + " ON u.iduser = r.iduser";
NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.addEntity("u", Users.class);
query.addEntity("r", UserRoles.class);
query.addEntity("a", Address.class);
```